# Use lining figures with Venturis ADF and hyperref

Tags: fonts, hyperref, venturis

I've got a document set with Venturis ADF and old style numbers, as they match the body text of the document much better. However, one of the characters names is Zen0, and with an old style zero this looks like Zeno. Therefore I'm using `\textl{Zen0}` to write hir name. This works perfectly fine, except in `\section` commands when I have `hyperref` enabled.

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{venturis}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\Zeno}{\textl{Zen0}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Zen0} %Works fine
\section{Zeno}
%\section{\textl{Zen0}} %Uncomment to break document
%\section{\lstyle Zen0} %Uncomment to break document

Zeno Zen0 \textl{Zen0} \Zeno

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\section{\texorpdfstring{\textl{Zen0}}{Zen0}}` (or whichever version you prefer for the 'PDF' string).

Comment: And of course, you might find it easier to put the `\texorpdfstring{<TeX>}{<PDF>}` command into your definition of `\Zeno`.

Comment: *Faceplam* Duhhhh. I've used this for Greek letters all the time. Should I just delete the question or do you want to answer it?

Comment: I suspect it must be a duplicate.  If not, I'd say keep it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hyperref` does not know `\lstyle` and `\textl`, thus these commands break the conversion of the section titles to bookmark text strings. `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` can be used to disable the new commands for the bookmarks. An alternative is using `\texorpdfstring`, see the comments.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{venturis}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \let\textl\@firstofone
  \let\lstyle\relax
}

\newcommand{\Zeno}{\textl{Zen0}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Zen0}
\section{Zeno}
\section{\textl{Zen0}}
\section{\lstyle Zen0}

Zeno Zen0 \textl{Zen0} \Zeno

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]